# Endnote x4 not launching files

Tags: windows, endnote

I have just started using Endnote. I have linked files (PDF) to my references, but now when I try to open them I get the following error.

Ive added the PDFs by right clicking on them and selecting open with Endnote, and they are all on a shared drive.

the box says:

The URL (\\Computer\folder1\folder2\folder3\pdfdoc.pdf)Could Not Be Launched

(obviously with the real folder names)

[image: error]

After communication with EndNote, they have said that there is an update that will prevent this problem. However they have been unable to come up with a solution to fix the already imported files.

Is there a fix for this problem?

Comment: The error message is displayed too small. Can you post the exact text?

Comment: I believe it says: This URL (\\\Imac-209838\groups\NeuroCoRe Server\Relevant Litegerature\New Folder\Microsoft Word - Ott 1998 Quantitative Assessment of Movement in AD.PDF) could not be launched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in Endnote 4. In order to resolve it download the latest update. As of yet I have not come across a solution to fixing the problem with pre-imported files, apart from re-importing them :(

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Endnote had a problem passing requests to Adobe. Also, the space in the UNC filepath can cause problems.

---

### Solution

Add a custom file handler script for PDF files.

- create a batch file containing `start "" "C:\path\to\Adobe\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" %1`
- save the file as `c:\PDF_Wrapper.bat`
- change the file association for `.PDF` files to `c:\PDF_Wrapper.bat`

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by changing the association for .pdf?

Comment: I just got an email back from endnote. they said to update the program to fix the bug, but there is nothing they can do in terms of fixing the previously imported files.